# Navigate through list with up/down arrows

Tags: jquery, list, navigation

Find the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aP5A3/1/

I'm trying to build a way for a user to navigate through the items of a list `#cityresults` by navigating with the up/down arrows.
When a user clicks the arrow down I want to apply class `activedropdownitem` on the active list item, and when he presses `Return` button while on that item I want to execute the same logic as when a user clicks with the mouse 
on that item, so in function `$('#cityresults').on('click', 'a', function ()`.

I copied a `Navigate` function from another site, but have no idea how to properly implement it.

```
<input id="city" name="city" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" class="textbox">
<input id="citygeonameid" name="citygeonameid" type="hidden">
<div id="cityresultscontainer">
    <div id="cityresults" style="display: block;">
        <ul>
        <li data-id="2750053"><a href="#" title="Nijmegen"><strong>Nij</strong>megen, Gelderland</a></li>
        <li data-id="2750065"><a href="#" title="Nijkerk"><strong>Nij</strong>kerk, Gelderland</a></li>
        <li data-id="2750089"><a href="#" title="Nijemirdum"><strong>Nij</strong>emirdum, Friesland</a></li>
        <li data-id="2750098"><a href="#" title="Nijega"><strong>Nij</strong>ega, Friesland</a></li>
        <li data-id="2990366"><a href="#" title="Nijon"><strong>Nij</strong>on, Champagne-Ardenne</a></li>
        <li data-id="2750094"><a href="#" title="Nijehaske"><strong>Nij</strong>ehaske, Friesland</a></li>
        <li data-id="2750104"><a href="#" title="Nij Altoenae"><strong>Nij</strong> Altoenae, Friesland</a></li>
        <li data-id="2750103"><a href="#" title="Nij Beets"><strong>Nij</strong> Beets, Friesland</a></li>
        <li data-id="8449187"><a href="#" title="Nijang"><strong>Nij</strong>ang, Nusa Tenggara Barat</a></li>
        <li data-id="2513222"><a href="#" title="Nijar"><strong>Nij</strong>ar, Andalusia</a></li>
        <li><span>Too many results? Refine your selection   </span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



var Navigate = function (diff) {
     displayBoxIndex += diff;
     var oBoxCollection = $("#cityresults");
     if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length)
         displayBoxIndex = 0;
     if (displayBoxIndex < 0)
         displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
     var cssClass = "display_box_hover";
     oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
 }

 window.displayBoxIndex = -1;
 $('#cityresults').on('click', 'a', function () {
     $('#city').val($(this).text());
     $('#cityresults').hide('');
     $('#citygeonameid').val($(this).parent().attr('data-id'));
     return false;
 });             

 $("#city").keyup(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) {
         return;
     }

     if (e.keyCode == 40) {
         //down arrow
         Navigate(1);
     }
     if (e.keyCode == 38) {
         //up arrow
         Navigate(-1);
     }

     if ($("#city").val().length > 1) {
        //here an ajax search is done

     }

 });
```

Comment: Post any CSS you have as well and if you can stick it all into a JSFiddle so we can toy with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I'll post the code and example for you then type the explanation so you can have something while you wait.  In the demo, make sure to click inside the display area or it won't capture your key presses (since JSFiddle uses an iframe).

## [Useful demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NjC58/)

### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.displayBoxIndex = -1;
    $('#cityresults').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('#city').val($(this).text());
        $('#cityresults').hide('');
        $('#citygeonameid').val($(this).parent().attr('data-id'));
        return false;
    });
    var Navigate = function (diff) {
        displayBoxIndex += diff;
        var oBoxCollection = $("#cityresults ul li a");
        if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length) {
            displayBoxIndex = 0;
        }
        if (displayBoxIndex < 0) {
            displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
        }
        var cssClass = "display_box_hover";
        oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
    }
    $(document).on('keypress keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
            $('.display_box_hover').trigger('click');
            return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            //down arrow
            Navigate(1);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            //up arrow
            Navigate(-1);
        }
    });
});
```

No change to the rest of the code.

Comment: You post answers my question, though I have one more question: I replaced the code `$(document).on` in your answer with `$("#city").on` to have it more specific. But now when I want to trigger a button click as soon as the user presses enter while the focus is on the `#city` field, how would I do that?

Comment: can you re-word that for me?  I don't quite understand your goal with that.

Comment: I believe you added this ` $(this).val($('.display_box_hover').text());`? What I need is that when cycling through the list an onenter wil fill the `#city` input with the selected value. This already happens. However, when the visitor presses the `return` button when focus is on `#city`, I want to trigger a click on the `#btnsearch` button (I updated your JSFiddle with this button). I believe that is different that what you've now implemented? Thanks again! :)

Comment: I'm gonna take that idea and run with it I just got this great picture in my mind so now I gotta make it real lol

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45015/discussion-between-deryck-and-flo)

Comment: Solved it. I used the `keydown` event (appending the current keyCode to the current #city value) and just checked whether an item with class 'display_box_hover' exists. If so, I use that to fill #city, if not I trigger a button click. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: oh wonderful.  literally 15 seconds after you left I had actually fixed it (it was a really easy thing too) but I'm glad you found what you were looking for. Happy coding :)