# How to make divs navigable by tab/down?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

In this example, I type in `java` and I hit tab/down, and I can start navigating the results. Its also sane as I can select the text and open the `learn more` link.

I want to make an autosuggest like this. **How do I** make it keyboard navigable as:

1. tab/down from textbox moves to first element
2. tab/down from an element moves to next element
3. up reverses both 1. and 2., you can move from an element to the textbox

---

I have tried setting tabindex to a bunch of elements. I can make them selectable, once selected I can only navigate **only** by tab (in Firefox), no up or down, much less going back to the textbox.

```
<textarea tabindex=1>something</textarea>
<ul>
<li tabindex=1>one item <a href="google.com">and link</a></li>
<li tabindex=1>one item</li>
<li tabindex=1 >one item</li>
</ul>
```

I also need to lay out everything consecutively in the HTML, whereas I usually add popovers as the last element to the body and absolutely position them.

I guess StackOverflow the site must be handling the tab, up and down keys and calculating which one gets focus; tabindex seems kinda limiting.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your tabindexes are all the same values. You need to make them incremental in the order you want them tabbed.

```
<textarea tabindex="1">something</textarea>
<ul>
<li tabindex="2">one item <a href="google.com">and link</a></li>
<li tabindex="3">one item</li>
<li tabindex="4">one item</li>
</ul>
```

This is assuming you're using HTML5.

Comment: But up/down arrows have no effect, much less navigating up. I did choose the same tabindex on purpose, tab will go through the divs in the order they were defined.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062543/navigate-through-list-with-up-down-arrows for an answer regarding arrow control.